# Why are so many simple types in the .Net framework not marked as serializable?

Tags: c#, serialization

I find it a recurring inconvenience that a lot of simple types in the .Net framework are not marked as serializable. For example: `System.Drawing.Point` or `Rectangle`.

Both those structs only consist of primitive data and should be serializable in any format easily. However, because of the missing [`System.Serializable`] attribute, I can't use them with a `BinaryFormatter`.

Is there any reason for this, which I'm not seeing?

Comment: something like this should work (look at solution #1) https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/110762/How-to-Serialize-Point-Pen-and-Brush

Comment: @Jacobr365 I think the question is more about why developers decided not to make them `Serializable`, not how to serializable them.

Comment: Aside from anything else, I'd generally recommend avoiding `BinaryFormatter` in the first place. I've found binary formatting to be terribly brittle...

Comment: It is just very hard to provide a guarantee that data that was serialized in version 1.0 can still be deserialized in version 4.7.  You have to think three times about adding a field to a class, that old serialized data isn't going to provide a value for it.  Microsoft took on the burden to provide that guarantee for BCL types, they could hardly do so for a GUI class library that was very likely to change in future versions.  Do note how this is a universal problem with any serialization scheme.  Easier when you can pass it off and make it somebody else's problem :)

Comment: It's a subtle hint that you should stay away from `BinaryFormatter` :)

Comment: Well, this is not about BinaryFormatter but about serializing in general. @Hans' comment probably nails it and imo is well worth being advanced to an answer.. (nudge nudge ;-)

Comment: Thank you! Now it seems pretty obvious to me, that versioning issues are a concern for a big framework that is maintained over many years. I just haven't thought about the fact, that it would be the .Net developers job to keep the BinaryFormatter working for all classes over many different versions. Text serialization like JSON or XML works fine without the attribute, because it can rely on reflection, data contracts or similar. I agree, maybe @HansPassant would like to change his comment to an answer?

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but no.  Far easier when I can pass it off and make it somebody else's problem to maintain such a hated answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a question of efficiency. Tagging a field as serializable the compiler must map each field onto a table of aliases. If they were all marked as serializables every object injecting or inheriting them need to be mapped aswell onto the table of aliases to process its serialization when probably you will never use them and it has a cost of memory and processing and it is more unsafe. Test it with millions of elements and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I believe it has less to do with the need to pass the buck, and more to do with the fact of usefulness and actual use, coupled with the fact that the .NET Framework is simply that, a framework. It is designed to be a stepping stone which provides you the basics to complete tasks that would otherwise be daunting in other languages, rather than do everything for you.

There really isn't anything stopping you from creating your own serialization mechanisms and extensions which provide the functionality you're seeking, or relying on many of the other products out there which are FOSS or paid which achieve this for you OOB.

Granted, @Hans Passant's answer is I think very close to the truth, there's a lot of other facets to this which go beyond just simply "It's not my problem." You can take it whatever way you want, but the ultimate thing you need to get out of it is, "where can I go from here?"